# How often are flag counts/allocation recalculated?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, flags

At about 20 hours prior to this post, I had exhausted all my moderator flags.

However, when I checked again about 8 hours later, I had 4 more flags.

*Unless memory has failed me*, it seems like flags are given out or recalculated more than once a day (at 0:00 UTC).  Is that true, and if so,

1. How often are they recalculated?
2. Can bad flagging during the day lose flags at the next recalc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You flag count is set back to `max` at midnight UTC.

`max` is a function of rep and `flag weight` (visible in your profile, unless it is at the default value, I believe).

`flag weight` is influenced by how many of your flags were deemed 'valid' by moderators.

If `flag weight` goes up during the UTC day such that `max` increases, you will receive the additional flags before the increase to `max` at midnight UTC.

Comment: Exactly as I understand it.  For completeness, insert before "I think" - 'If `flag weight` goes up during the UTC day such that `max` increases, you will receive the additional flags before the increase to `max` at midnight UTC.'

Comment: This answer states known facts.. @Jon I guess you're adding that you observe the same re flags being added _during the day_?

Comment: @rich, I'm guessing @Jon's comment is the answer to  your question?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is in addition to Jon's comment, which I'm fairly certain is one reason for this to happen.

When I only had 5 spam flags I had this happen to me quite a few times, where I'd flag 5 answers as spam and a moderator would go in and delete them, and I'd get my 5 flags back. This might be dependant on exactly how the flag is handled and also what kind of flag it is, and I'm not sure if it happens anymore since it's not as easy keeping track of the number of flags left now.

Though I think there's the same or at least a similar issue with flag weight. A few days ago I flagged a bunch of answers as spam, and later I noticed that my flag weight had gone up, but a little later I noticed that my flag weight had gone down to the exact number as it was previous to flagging those answers. All the answers were from the same user, so I assumed that maybe a mod had deleted the whole user account and all related posts and this might be side effect.